# Login to Ubuntu fails

Tags: login-screen

I restarted my laptop and then I could not log into Ubuntu desktop or console even. I tried to login at console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. But on console, it does not login as well. On desktop it takes password and after a blink returns back to login screen again. I have study data and everything and kind of stuck in this login issue. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you reboot, and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> after the Power On Self Test disappears? If there is a `Recovery Mode` line item, please cursor down and choose it.

Comment: thanks. I went to recover mode and clear some space and it worked